# multiply all values retrieved from mysql with a constant

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I am retrieving all values of a database in the form of two rows and need to multiply all values with a single constant. 
mysql query:

```
$book= "SELECT distinct names, values FROM table1 where address =?"
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmm, "s", $usa);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($sttm);
        $result= mysqli_stmt_get_result($sttm);
        $ress = mysqli_fetch_array($result)
```

In the while loop I want to multiply all these values with a predefined variable $calc:
I now want to do something like this:

```
        $i = 1;     
    while($ress = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {   
        echo '<tr><td>'.$i.'</td>';
        $i += 1;
        echo '<td>'.$ress['names'].' </td>';
        echo '<td> '.$ress['values']*$calc.'</td>';
}
echo '</tr></table>';
}
```

Please help

Comment: Typo? Should be $rows['XXX'] instead of $ress['XXX'] in the loop. Otherwise you will not get all the rows.  `</tr>` should also be in the loop.

Comment: yes, that was a typo. but the loop doesn't seem to be working. All my values  returned are 0

Comment: You may var_dump your $result to check the SQL query result.

Comment: what is the error? it would help if you include those

Answer (score 1):

you might have problem in `while` loop.

you can use `foreach`, while you have records in `(array)$ress`

```
    foreach($ress as $key => $row)
    {   
        echo '<tr><td>'.$key.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['names'].' </td>';
        echo '<td> '.($ow['values'] * $calc).'</td>';
    }
   echo '</tr></table>';
```

Comment: i had update the answer, see there may be some help for you

Comment: var_dump  $ress see query executed successfully ?

Answer (score 1):

I think that your didn't fetch data from your database. Your loop section also has some HTML tag match problem. I tried the following code with my local database, the loop section works well.

```
<?php 
include '../inc/conn_stackoverflow.php';
$book= $con->prepare("SELECT distinct `date`, cntr FROM counter where id >?");
$usa=0;
$book->bind_param("i", $usa);
mysqli_stmt_execute($book);
$result= mysqli_stmt_get_result($book);
//echo "<pre>";
//var_dump($result);
$calc=100;

echo "<table>";
$i=1;
while($ress = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {   
        echo '<tr><td>'.$i.'</td>';
        $i += 1;
        echo '<td>'.$ress['date'].' </td>';
        echo '<td> '.((float)$ress['cntr']*(float)$calc).'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Answer (score 1):

there are some reason for this not to work

main reason is that the data retrieved from database is not int type, i think the $ress['values'] is returning a string so you need to check it or parse it to int before multiplying